# Can I see if cloudwatch logs has been rejecting any of my events (due to event size)

Tags: amazon-web-services, logging, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs, aws-cloudwatch-log-insights

I use cloud watch logs to view my backend's output to console.log(). Recently some events have started not appearing (events where I am logging large objects). Is there any way for me to see what events cloud watch has rejected.

If I could see the event size too that would be very useful. I don't think my events are over 20kb a time (so I would be surprised if cloud watch was rejecting them as I read the max event size is 256kb).

Thank you

Comment: Are you using `console.log(JSON.stringify(bigObject));` when logging? Also, keep in mind, CloudWatch tends to lag behind sometimes.

Comment: yes i am using JSON.stringify. It's behind by about 10 days and some other things I'm logging are coming through. Very confused why I'm not seeing my logged objects

Comment: That's not good, the lag should be at most a few minutes in my experience. The batch size for CloudWatch is `1MB` (event size  is`256KB`, as you said), you should be able to log huge objects. I suspect the issue is somewhere else. I suggest checking the IAM policies CloudWatch. Or you may want to investigate if the CloudWatch agent is working correctly on your instance where the backend is deployed.